# SQL Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error

Tags: sql, oracle

I am experiencing below error on execution of trigger:

```
SQL Error: ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
ORA-06512: at "Test.ADD_DUMMY_RULE", line 13


create or replace
TRIGGER "ADD_DUMMY_RULE" 
BEFORE DELETE ON testTable
   FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
old.product_id != 0
      )
DECLARE
 pcnt  NUMBER(14);

BEGIN
 pcnt := 0;

trig_pkg.rowIndex := trig_pkg.rowIndex + 1;

 -- STORING IMAGE_ID
 trig_pkg.old_image_id := :OLD.image_id;

 IF (trig_pkg.rimage_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
  FOR i IN 1..(trig_pkg.hold_imid_tablsize) LOOP
   IF (trig_pkg.old_image_id = trig_pkg.rimage_id(i)) THEN
    pcnt := pcnt + 1;
   END IF;
  END LOOP;
 END IF;

END;
```

Please suggest what could be the cause of issue.

**Edit**

datatypes:

```
trig_pkg.rowIndex - Number
trig_pkg.rimage_id - IS TABLE OF INTEGER INDEX BY binary_integer;
trig_pkg.hold_imid_tablsize- NUMBER(14)
```

Comment: what type do   rimage_id  have ?

Comment: @schurik, rimage_id type is Number

Comment: What type is `trig_pkg.hold_imid_tablsize`? More importantly, do you have more than one trigger - the code is for `ADD_DUMMY_RULE_`, the error is for `ADD_DUMMY_RULE` (without the trailing underscore) - is that something you've introduced in the question, or is that what you're really seeing?

Comment: @AlexPoole, yes it is a typo..trig_pkg.hold_imid_tablsize is Number

Comment: you cannot use a Number as a collection:  **rimage_id(i)**

Comment: Does `trig_pkg.hold_imid_tablsize` always have a value or can it be `null` at some point? (Not sure if 1..null would cause ORA-06502 though?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to remove the following IF part string

```
IF (trig_pkg.rimage_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
```

`INDEX BY` - Tables do not need to initialized

Comment: rimage_id type is not Number...I have editied the question with types and please review and suggest..

Comment: i have review my answer

Comment: thanks for guiding me in right direction, trig_pkg.hold_imid_tablsize does not any value(even null)...